# How can I split the table in Peewee

Tags: python, mysql, peewee

I am using `peewee` to make our project easy to operate database.
Actually, I have a problem with peewee recently.

```
class User(Model):
    id = IntegerField()
    name = CharField()

    Class Meta:
        database = db # db connection
        db_table = 'user_00' # Here is the problem
```

We have a lot of users, and I have to split the table like

```
user_00,user_01,user_0...user_09.
```

If I use the field `db_table`, I can't do that, and I also don't want to create more model.

BTW, I know the function called `db_table_func`, but there are no more usage in the doc.

How do you use the split table in your project?

Thx, I really need help!

Comment: How large is your table?

Comment: Maybe 80g? We have a lot of tables had split before, I can't change anything actually. Do you have any ideas for that ? :(